# Octave/Matlab: change value at certain position in matix

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization

I have a vector which tells me where in matrix I have to change certain bit and matrix with data. For example:

```
a = [2
     0
     4]

data = [ 1 0 1 0;
         0 0 1 0
         1 1 1 1]
```

a tells me, I have to change (flip from 1 to 0) the folowing values:

- 2nd column in 1st row
- 4rd column in 3rd row
- in 2nd row there is no change !!!

the result would be

```
data2 = [ 1 1 1 0;
          0 0 1 0
          1 1 1 0]
```

How can I do that with only vector operations? I don't want to use for loops because they are too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a way to do that:

```
   data2=data;
   ind=sub2ind(size(data),find(a),a(a>0));
   data2(ind)=~data(ind)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. I tried your code, but something seems to be still missing. If I use that code on the example data I get the following:
data2 = [1 1 1 1; 0 0 1 0; 1 0 1 0], so it flips some additional bits.

Comment: yes, I see why it is happening, I used linear indexing without being too careful. see my edit for the fix.